# Why are functions passed in an options object in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I instantiate a new view like this:

```
var myView = new viewOne({
    myFunction: function(){//do something}
});
```

When I call that function from within the view, I'm having to call `this.objects.myFunction()` rather than simply `this.myFunction();`

Is this because backbone automatically passes functions of a view in an object called options, or is there another reason this is happening? Note that I have a few functions in the view, not just one. Thanks!

Comment: Backbone used to do that but stopped in version 1.1.0: ["Backbone Views no longer automatically attach `options` passed to the constructor as `this.options` ..."](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog). Other than than, that's just how they chose to set things up.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
initialize: function(){
_.bindAll(this, "myFunction");
},
myFunction: function(){do something}
```